# Apply Hyperlink to a CSS Created DIV

Tags: html, css

I need to figure out a way to have the Yellow Box `<div id="bottom">` and the Text `<div id="basket">SHOP NOW</div>`link to google.com for example.

I have tried adding `<div id="bottom"><a href="www.google.com" class="fill-div"></a>
</div>` but nothing is working. It appears to skew the entire section when I add this syntax.

I have searched all over the place looking for an answer, I have read through almost all related StackOverflow articles and still can't figure out the correct way to do this.

Here is a link https://jsfiddle.net/sixpac/8p4m7oc2/8/ to my code.

Can someone point me in the right direction with this? Is this possible to complete without JavaScript? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for something like this https://jsfiddle.net/8p4m7oc2/13/

```
<div id="bottom">
    <a href="google.com" id="basket">SHOP NOW</a>
    <div id="price"><a href="google.com">$70.00</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank You @alebruck - Does this basically create 2 (two) links? Essentially doubling up with this?

Comment: Yep, each <a>  tag is a different hyperlink

Comment: Thanks again, now after playing with it, I understand it.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the div element in an anchor element to have it link to your chosen url / file.

i.e.

```
<a href="www.google.com" class="fill-div">
<div id="bottom">
</div>
</a>
```

This should be the code:

https://jsfiddle.net/RreTH/

Edit:

This will make the whole div element link to google for linking just the text the `<a href="example"></a>` should be enough to link only the text.

Answer (score 1):

Simply change the `basket` div to `<a>`:

```
<a id="basket" href="http://www.google.com">SHOP NOW</a>
```